# How can I make a dashed line on a road that completely follows a curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

I want to create a dashed line in the middle of a road which follows a curve using Geometry Nodes.

The problem in my current setup is that the individual 'dashes" don"t follow the curve since they are defined as cubes. This causes them to disappear at certain places or float a bit above the surface.

Would it be possible to make the dashes follow the road in the same way the full white lines do?

The Blender file is in attachment under the images.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the geometry not to overlap with the other, it would have to follow exactly the topology of the road.

You can solve that this way:

[image]

Here I use the same curve that you use to create the road, but convert it to a mesh line.

This way I can delete single points, so that gaps are created. These mesh lines are then converted back into curves, so that these segments do not differ from the original curve in terms of the position of the points (apart from the gaps).

Finally, as with the other objects, you convert this curve to a mesh using `Curve to Mesh`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: This is great! :-D I wouldn't have found this solution by myself. Thanks a lot Stephan! A paypal coffee is underway.

Comment: @PieterLéon Always a pleasure! Thanks for the coffee!