# How to put white road markings on the asphalt of a highway in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry, mathematics

I ask this question in relation to my previous question on this topic: [link here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/289200/how-can-i-make-a-dashed-line-on-a-road-that-completely-follows-a-curve)

This was resolved by Quellenform (many thanks!), but now I am encountering another problem:

When the road/curve is level on the ground without elevation it works like a charm, but when there is a strong elevation or the road makes sharp turns, the road surface starts to "wobble" within the faces that make up the surface. I exemplify this in the images below.

This results in the dashed or full white lines not 'sticking' to the road surface and disappearing in other places.

The problem also seems to get worse the farther off from the center (the curve).

Blender file in attachment here:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The reason the lines stand out irregularly from the roadway is because the roadway's quads are triangulated in the end. So, just a dumb question, but are you sure you want to build this with Geometry Nodes? I think a shader would be better here and actually no geometry would be needed for this. Or not?

Comment: Those road markings will destroy your tires! And even if you want slight bumps on them, this is such a subtle difference - and never affecting the silhouette - that you should achieve it with normal - bump in the shader.

Comment: Hello Stephan and Michael,

Thank you very much for your answers and feedback. Thanks for the example you worked out Markus!

The reason I wanted to do it with geometry nodes is because I am making a modular road system and I want to have procedural control over each white line on the road: turn them on/ off individually, make them dashed or full. control the length of the dashes and gaps.

Comment: I see your point that making this with material nodes would have many advantages.
The only thing is: when I work with drivers to control the individual white lines on the road in a material, it will change in all the objects which have this material applied to it. It doesn't have the same versatility as GeoNodes for that if I'm not mistaken.

I guess it's best to open a new question about this so I can explain it better?

Comment: @PieterLéon you can similarly control this in a shader, though as you notice, a material doesn't have an object-specific modifier like geometry nodes do. You can read a custom property: https://i.imgur.com/bYIdVlT.png Or you can use geonodes to capture a named attribute and also read it with "attribute" node, but using "Geometry" mode, or "Instancer" if you captured in instance domain.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for that explanation. It would be great if there would be a possibility that the solution stays within Geometry Nodes so I can connect all kinds of things to it. I'm afraid tho that what you are saying is a bit above my level of understanding. I made a new question about this. Would you mind looking at it?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294465/how-to-have-the-same-material-applied-on-multiple-objects-but-control-the-mater
Thanks in advance already!

Answer (score 3):

Consider capturing the length of the road as well as the perpendicular coordinate. I don't capture it as some kind of UVMap vector, because I would need to split it in the shader anyway. Also subdivide to deal with the artifacts coming from curve pinching and ugly triangulation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]